# Запретить «бюро переводов»?

Tags: предложение, закрытие-вопросов

<sub>Возможно, этот вопрос уже задавался, но я поиском не
нашёл.</sub>

Некоторые теги, в особенности `[pascal]`, страдают от
вопросов типа «Помогите перевести код с языка *X* на язык
*Y*».  Частые проблемы с этими вопросами:

1. Они часто **не несут пользы для сообщества**, так как не
   содержат конкретной проблемы, которую можно найти поисковиком.
2. Они походят на **домашние задания**, либо являются
   решениями этих самых домашних заданий на «неправильном» языке.
3. Они иногда представляют из себя три страницы **кода в плохом стиле
   и без форматирования** и комментариев, делая собственно перевод
   более тяжёлым.

Поэтому предлагаю закрывать подобные вопросы, если в них:

1. Языки программирования по мнению сообщества **мало
   различаются** в том, как они представляют алгоритмы (например,
   *Pascal* и *C++* различаются не так сильно, как *Python*
   и *Erlang*).
2. Нет свидетельств, что ОП пытался сделать задание
   **самостоятельно**.

Сейчас они часто закрываются как домашки, но возможно следует добавить
отдельную причину закрытия, чтобы подчеркнуть, что простыми переводами
сообщество не занимается.  Кроме того, отдельная причина позволит
подчеркнуть случаи, когда перевод может быть полезен.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Существующих причин вполне достаточно для всех оттенков "Переводов":

> Непонятна суть вопроса
>   В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Если действительно непонятно, с чем конкретно у автора проблема. Если автор просто запостил кусок кода без пояснений в чем его затруднения.

---

> Необходимо конкретизировать
>   Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Вопрос слишком широк, нужно конкретизировать, автор не знает синтаксиса, структур, аналогов методов, чего-то еще? Вопрос должен быть сфокусирован, чтобы быть полезным.

---

> Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Вопрос упоминает проблему, но не представляет ее в достаточно краткой манере. Если проблема с частью переводного кода - нужно убрать лишнее и оставить только эту часть.

---

> Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу 1

Аналогично.

Comment: первые три пункта вполне покрывают учебные вопросы, но почему-то все равно ввели отдельный пункт :)

Comment: Пункт с домашками, я так понимаю, введен, т.к. у РуСО есть пара слотов для "своих причин" закрытия, и домашки - самая большая и популярная причина, после (и вместе с) остальных.

Comment: @Kromster специализировать причины - неплохое решение. Мы новых причин можем ещё понадобавлять)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik  Вы, наверное, шутите, но именно об этом мой изначальный пост.  Мне кажется, что проблема переводов достаточно специфична.  Видимо, другие участники с этим не согласны.  Если других мнений не будет, отмечу ответ Kromster как верный.

Comment: @Ainar-G если вы хотите обсудить именно добавление новой причины, то лучше это в заголовке отразить или новым вопросом)

Answer (score 7):

Пользуясь случаем, хоть и немного не в тему, хотел бы попросить сообщество не врубать негатив на вопросы с "переводом" по умолчанию. Желательно, конечно, что бы вопрос был максимально конкретный, что-то вроде "Как конструкция X из языка A реализуется в языке Б?".
Тогда, он будет максимально полезен, и очень хорошо приводить людей из поисковиков.

Я выступаю за подобные вопросы, потому что сам сталкивался, как иной раз трудно, пока ещё не вник в дух языка, понять как *нормально* сделать что-либо. Пару раз я отвечал на подобные вопросы здесь, когда речь шла про перевод между языками, которые я знаю. И я искренне удивлялся в процессе насколько это на самом деле не просто, сколько нюансов зарыто, и что иной раз точно не перевести (прям как с естественными языками).

Но видимо из-за переизбытка совсем некачественных вопросов, нормальные получают минуса, закрытия, и что самое плохое игнор.